# Unable to play Snapchat videos

Tags: video, samsung-galaxy-ace, snapchat

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace and I am unable to view most videos on Snapchat that people send to me. I have tried to rectify the problem by downloading MX player and VLC player and updating to Snapchat beta. However I am still unable to view almost all Snapchat videos and was wondering how I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to resolve your issue by below ideas.

1. Your device may not support the quality in which user has recorded that video.
2. You need to clear cache memory of phone, or reboot your phone.
3. Size of video is so large, it will be unable to view that in your net speed(2G).
4. You should try deleting the app and re-downloading.